# WPF - Programmatically Binding to DataGridCheckBoxColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, binding

I'm trying to programmatically bind an IList to a datagrid and one of the columns is a boolean value, so I decided to use a DataGridCheckBoxColumn instead of my usual DataGridTextColumn.  Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be working.

This the code I am currently using:

```
DataGridCheckBoxColumn dgcbc = new DataGridCheckBoxColumn();
Binding b = new Binding("Convicted");

dgcbc.Header = "Convicted";
dgcbc.Binding = b;
this.dgResults.Columns.Add(dgcbc);
```

After I set the source for the DataGrid the checkbox column shows up, but they are all unchecked.  If I switch the DGCBC back to a DGTC the binding correctly shows up as either "true" or "false".  Any ideas?

Comment: The code you posted works just fine, just tried it. Something else must be the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your binding need to be Mode=TwoWay?

Comment: Nope.  It's for display purposes only.