# From XAML to C#. How to add DataGrid to WrapPanel that corresponds the one in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to create DataGrid with Binding that corresponds the one in XAML.

```
 <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" Name="myWrapPanel" Margin="20,120,20,0">
    <DataGrid BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Name="myDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AlternatingRowBackground="#8A2BE2" RowBackground="#FFA40000" Background="{x:Null}" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="True" HeadersVisibility="None" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="340" >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="10">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding Path=one, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="4*">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="NoWrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="TAG" Text="{Binding Path=two}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="5*">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=three, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </WrapPanel>
```

Unfortunately one created dynamically is not the same.
Checkbox looks different, margins are not right.
This is my code so far:

```
        DataGrid myDataGrid2 = new DataGrid();
        myDataGrid2.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        myDataGrid2.AlternatingRowBackground = (Brush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#8A2BE2"));
        myDataGrid2.RowBackground = (Brush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#FFA40000"));
        myDataGrid2.CanUserAddRows = false;
        myDataGrid2.CanUserDeleteRows = true;
        myDataGrid2.HeadersVisibility = DataGridHeadersVisibility.None;
        myDataGrid2.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        myDataGrid2.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0);

        Binding one = new Binding();
        one.Path = new PropertyPath("one");
        one.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
        one.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;

        DataGridCheckBoxColumn One = new DataGridCheckBoxColumn();
        One.Width = 10;
        One.Binding = one;

        Binding two = new Binding();
        two.Path = new PropertyPath("two");
        two.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
        two.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;

        DataGridTextColumn Two = new DataGridTextColumn();
        Two.Width = new DataGridLength(4, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);
        Two.Binding = two;

        Binding three = new Binding();
        three.Path = new PropertyPath("three");
        three.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
        three.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;

        DataGridTextColumn Three = new DataGridTextColumn();
        Three.Width = new DataGridLength(5, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);
        Three.Binding = three;

        myDataGrid2.Width = this.Width - 40;
        myDataGrid2.Height = myDataGrid2.RowHeight * myDataGrid2.Items.Count + 20;

        myDataGrid2.Columns.Add(One);
        myDataGrid2.Columns.Add(Two);
        myDataGrid2.Columns.Add(Three);
        myWrapPanel.Children.Add(myDataGrid2);

        myDataGrid2.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<Driver>(driver);
```

This is my first app in WPF. 
Any help?

Bindig works great, only the visuals are the problem.
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/194/8iok.png/
As you can see on the image, upper section is in XAML, bottom in C#.
I want to add some data dynamically, after some threads end.
That's the main point.

Comment: Why would you try to write it in code? It's very rare to do this in normal WPF app.

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably create a `Style` with the properties set up, then use that for both `myDataGrid` and `myDataGrid2`.  E.g. something along the lines of:

```
// in current file's Resources section
<Style x:Key="MyDataGridStyle">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}" />
    // other stuff...
    <Setter Property="Columns">
        <Setter.Value>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="10">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding Path=one, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="4*">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="NoWrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="TAG" Text="{Binding Path=two}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="5*">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=three, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
 </Style>


 <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" Name="myWrapPanel" Margin="20,120,20,0">
    <DataGrid Name="myDataGrid" Style="{StaticResource MyDataGridStyle}" />
 </WrapPanel>

DataGrid myDataGrid2 = new DataGrid();
myDataGrid2.Style = (Style)this.Resources["MyDataGridStyle"];
```

Answer (score 0):

What is not working? 
The binding? The datagrid visually?

Please be more specific.

From what I've seen in your code everything looks right.
Can you try adding the items manually (add them manually to myDataGrid2.Items)?

Besides that there is also some issues with two way indings, that might be your case (see [WPF - Programatically Binding to DataGridCheckBoxColumn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147833/wpf-programatically-binding-to-datagridcheckboxcolumn) )

Comment: Bindig works great, only the visuals are the problem. [link](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/194/8iok.png/) As you can see on the image, upper section is in XAML, bottom in C#.

Comment: Probably it is a Style issue like Tim S. answered